# whats the best way to echo a php tag inclusive in a while loop?

Tags: php, url

```
<a href="edit-post.php?id=<?php echo $row['postID'];?>">Edit</a> |
```

This is a simple url...
The issue is I have to echo it in a while loop.
Which means I cant use php tags.

MY cancatenation sucks... I tried it for hours (noob) Please help

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is I have to echo it in a while loop. Which means I cant use php tags.

It doesn't mean that.

```
<?php
    while ($condition) {
?>
        <a href="edit-post.php?id=<?php echo $row['postID'];?>">Edit</a> | 
<?php
    }
?>
```

(But if you have a list of links, then use list markup (`ul`/`ol`/`li`) not `|` characters).

Comment: really? I never new that. Thanks... I was asuming it would cut of the loop? maybe

Comment: +1 good answer - yes it does not mean that you can't use php tags + in such things there is no need to use php tags like that you can do it as I have told you in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
echo '<a href="edit-post.php?id='.$row["postID"].'">Edit</a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple:

```
<?php
While(condition){
?>
<a href="edit-post.php?id=<?php echo $row['postID'];?>">Edit</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: what is new in your answer?! (-0.5)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to "prepare" the whole  element in php. Something like this:

```
foreach ($arr as $key) {
      print '<a href="edit-post.php?id=<' . $key . '">Edit</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    while ($condition) {
        echo '<a href="edit-post.php?id='.$row["postID"].'">Edit</a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think you could put a +1 to others answer instead.)-: (-0.5) ie. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use heredoc syntax.
Sidenote, I would collect them all and echo it out once in the end

```
$text = '';

while ($foo) {
    $text .= '<a href="edit-post.php?id='.$row["postID"].'">Edit</a>';
}

echo $text;

// or heredoc

$text = '';

while ($foo) {
    $text .= <<<_HTML
            <a href="edit-post.php?id={$row["postID"]}">Edit</a>
_HTML;
}

echo $text;

// or array

while ($foo) {
    $data[] = '<a href="edit-post.php?id='.$row["postID"].'">Edit</a>';
}

if(!empty($data)){
  echo '<p>'.implode('</p><p>',$data).'</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is a template file in php then always use this type of syntax

**code:**

```
    <?php 
     $i=0;
     while($i<10) : ?>
     <div><?php echo $i;?></div>
     <?php 
     $i++; 
     endwhile;?>
```